# odac client 11.2.0.1.2 installation/re-installation but no oracle submenu at view menu of VS 2010

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net, odac

To whom it may respond to ,
I have installed/re-installed odac client 11.2.0.1.2 but there is not any oracle sub-menu appearing in the view menu of Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel
Any ideas as resolution?

Thank you for your time and concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by cleaning up all the files in the app folder and re-installing again.